# How do you delete and rename tables from MapDB 3.x?

Tags: java, mapdb

In MapDB 1.x, you could easily delete tables from the MapDB by calling `db.delete("table name")` and `db.rename("old table name", "new table name")`.
But there seems to be no API functionality to do either of the above anymore.

How do you delete and rename tables in MapDB 3.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In comments of `Db.delete()` from version `1.0`, there is the following:

> /** delete record/collection with given name*/.

So `delete()` was actually deleting named records/collections. Of course latter can be perceived as tables.

One major change in the project (since version 1.0) was the conversion to `kotlin`.

After this, a big refactoring seems to have happened on April 2018.
See entry: `Commits on Apr 5, 2018` from  https://github.com/jankotek/mapdb/commits/master/src/main/java/org/mapdb/DB.kt

In this day `delete()` was removed from `Db.tk` and a `Store` containing `put/update/delete` was created.

`db.getStore().delete()` might be what you want to use.

Comment: @Nicholas DiPiazza Did you figure out how to use db.getStore().delete()?